# Image size of image in an NSButton

Tags: cocoa, nsimage, nsbutton

I'm trying to add an image to an `NSButton`. No matter what dimensions I make the image it is being cropped (see the button to the left in the screenshot). This is a simple `NSRoundedBezelStyle` `NSButton`. In this case my image is 15x15 and the button has a height of 26 and a width of 45.

What is the correct way to create and add an image to an `NSButton` so that it is displayed properly?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What is the exact filename of the image in question? (Is the image intended to be used as a "template" image (doesn't look like it)?

Comment: icon_forward_button.png

Comment: I'm not familiar with template images - is that what I should be using here?